# Plotting Candlestick in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, quantitative-finance

I'd like to plot a candlestick of a promising company. My code is in follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
yf.pdr_override()

#My python 3.6 seem in trouble using pandas_datareader directly,so I install a makeup

gree=pdr.get_data_yahoo('000651.SZ', start='2000-01-01',end='2018-04-30')
gree.info()
gree['Close'].plot(grid=True,figsize=(8,5))
gree['42d']=pd.rolling(gree['Close'],window=42).mean()
gree['42d']=np.round(pd.rolling(gree['Close'],window=42).mean(),2)
gree['252d']=np.round(pd.rolling_mean(gree['Close'],window=252),2)
gree[['Close','42d','252d']].tail()
```

I met a problem:
    AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling'.
Though I have read almost every available answer,I have no idea how to solve it. Could you do me a favor? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need [`Series.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html), check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#window-functions-are-now-methods):

So change:

```
gree['42d']=pd.rolling(gree['Close'],window=42).mean()
gree['42d']=np.round(pd.rolling(gree['Close'],window=42).mean(),2)
gree['252d']=np.round(pd.rolling_mean(gree['Close'],window=252),2)
```

to:

```
gree['42d'] = gree['Close'].rolling(window=42).mean().round(2)
gree['252d'] = gree['Close'].rolling(window=252).mean().round(2)
```

Or if use pandas bellow `0.18.0`:

```
gree['42d'] = pd.rolling_mean(gree['Close'],window=42)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. The problem also appears :AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_mean'

Comment: Sure, need `gree['42d'] = gree['Close'].rolling(window=42).mean()`

Comment: So both solutions failed?